# How to run Zend bootstrap only for variables, without running controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

As above. Is it possible? Running $application->bootstrap()->run() processes Index action in Index controller, but I don't need it.

Comment: Can you clarify this? I'm not sure we know what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

Given that you have a "default" like starting PHP file like https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/zf/release-2.2.6/public/index.php

Just change the last line from

```
Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();
```

to

```
$app = Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php');
//$app->run(); <- dont do this
```